# What design pattern bootstrap v4 uses on the click event

Tags: javascript, design-patterns, bootstrap-4

Here is a snippet I am trying to figure out

```
$(document).on(
Event.CLICK_DATA_API,
Selector.DISMISS,
Alert._handleDismiss(new Alert()) )
```

This snippet is part of the Alert component:

https://github.com/twbs/bootstrap/blob/v4-dev/js/src/alert.js

I am trying to understand why on a click event we are trying to pass a `new Alert()` rather than just an instance of or let the event.target do the heavy lifting on the listener.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After further review of the code, the reason why a new instance is passed as an argument it is because an Alert instance didn't exist at the time of the click event. Which in reality it is an elegant way to only create an instance when needed.

I was also provided through other channels that the pattern used is for 'event delegation'.